# How to clear cache from ES6 Import Module (React Native)?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I am new to React native i just build the app with two screen and using navigation like login screen and my profile screen.

I create UserData module and import this file in my profile screen. like this

```
import * as UserData from '../modules/UserData';
```

Press the logout button navigation navigate back to the login screen.

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                                    index: 0,
                                    actions: [
                                        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LoginStack' })
                                    ],
                                });
                            this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

then i login using another user id it's going to my profile screen but UserData module just still keep the Previous login user datas. How to avoid this i have no idea. Someone Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when logout , you must delete all the old state and props of components , StackActions.reset do not auto delete this

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method on press of the logout button and in that method you need to clear the async storage and all the mobx/redux stores. After clearing the data, you navigate the user to login page and reset the navigation.